# bibtex format for url reference

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

How do I add a note after a URL in URL reference using BibTeX in IEEE format? My code looks like this

```
@misc{thz_net,
 title={Terahertz applications },
 url={http://thznetwork.net/index.php/thz-images},
 note={(Date last accessed 15-July-2014)},
 }
```

Note appears before the url like this

> [2] “Terahertz applications,” (Date last accessed 15-July-2014). [Online].
>   Available: http://thznetwork.net/index.php/thz-images

I'd like the note to appear after the URL. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5):

Consider using `biblatex-ieee` and the `urldate` field rather than `note`. The default string for urldate  is`visited on` (in English). If you prefer the string  produced in your question, uncomment the 3 commented lines.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[style = ieee, urldate =comp]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{xpatch}
    \usepackage{url}

    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{thz_net,
    title={Terahertz applications },
    url={http://thznetwork.net/index.php/thz-images},
    urldate={2014-07-15},
    }
    \end{filecontents}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
% urlseen = {Date last accessed on}%
% }

    \begin{document}

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography

    \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that modifying a copy of the file `IEEEtran.bst` to achieve your objective is not particular difficult. I suggest you perform the following steps:

- Find the file `IEEEtran.bst` in your TeX distribution. (If you run TeXLive, it probably resides at `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/IEEEtran/`.)
- Make a copy of this file -- don't edit a file from your TeX distribution directly -- and call the copy, say, `myIEEEtran.bst`.
- Open the file `myIEEEtran.bst` in your favorite text editor. The editor you use for your .tex files will do fine.
- Find the function called `misc`. (In my copy of this file, the function `misc` starts on line 2144.)
- In this function, locate the two lines that say

  ```
    format.note output
    format.url output
  ```

  Exchange the ordering of these two lines so that `format.url` will be executed *before* `format.note`.
- Save the file `myIEEEtran.bst`, either in the directory where you main tex file is located, or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update your TeX distribution's filename database appropriately.
- Start using the "new" bibliography style file by issuing the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{myIEEEtran.bst}
  ```

  The first time you use the new style file, be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,url}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{thz_net,
 title={Terahertz applications },
 url={http://thznetwork.net/index.php/thz-images},
 note={(Date last accessed 15-July-2014)},
 }
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{myIEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works! However, I did not know where to place the myIEEEtran.bst. Also, texhash did not pick it up and kpsewhich command returned no path. So I just added the bst file to the same folder as my tex file, worked like a breeze.

Comment: @user29898 - I'm glad it works for you. Incidentally, in the second-to-last bullet point I did suggest that the new file could be saved in the directory where the main tex file is stored.

Comment: I don't know **why** but it works just fine :) thanks (+1). Maybe you want to elaborate the "why" and how you found out - I would be very interested.

Comment: I tried this, but in my case after doing this pdf did not generate references. I am using texstudio, I run .tex file many times.

Comment: @Infinity - You mention that you run TeX -- I'm assuming you meant LaTeX. But do you run BibTeX too?

Comment: @Mico yes I did pdfLatex bibtex pdfLatex pdfLatex

Comment: @Mico when I put myIEEEtran.bst in the same folder as main.tex, then the solution works. I think problem is that texstudio could not find myIEEEtran.bst. I put it in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bst\ieeetran folder, how can I make it to load from the default location, where IEEEtran.bst is?

Comment: @Infinity - My apologies for the rather late reply. As I wrote in the next.-to-last bullet point, "Save the file `myIEEEtran.bst`, either in the directory where you main tex file is located, or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, *be sure to update your TeX distribution's filename database appropriately*" [emphasis added]. Since MikTeX is your TeX distribution, the "update the filename database appropriately" instruction involves firing up the MikTeX utility that lets you update MikTeX's filename database.

Answer (score 0):

with this patch [1] for IEEEtranN.bst the *urldate* entry will be shown with ieeeTran 1.8a

don't forget to update your tex installation with

```
 texconfig-sys rehash
```

hopefully it's in the next release

[1] http://pastebin.com/fqSS9fRX

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please consider moving the bulk of the patch file to the body of your posting. I would also be helpful if you indicated how a user might make use of the patch if their TeX distribution doesn't run on a Unix-based system.